How do I perfectly cover an edge with cubes?
I'm trying to distribute cubes on a bunch of axis aligned edges. This was my attempt:

Split edges node to make sure I get no interpolation on the attributes
Store the length of the edge in an attribute
Store the amount of cubes in an edge. Right now it's simply max(1, (abs(floor(edge_length)) (or simply, the rounded edge_length with at least a single cube)
Store the length of each cube (edge_length / cube_count)
Using the Scale Elements node, scale the edges to subtract 1 cube_length.

The reasoning is that I will need to turn the edges into a curve to distribute the cubes, and since the cubes sit on the vertices of the curve, half of the first cube and half of the last cube are "outside" the edge, so I subtract 1 cube from the edge length.


Mesh to Curve node is used to divide the edge and the count parameter is the stored cube_count
Instances on points node to add the cubes and scale them using the cube_length

This almost works:

But notice that while larger edges are covered correctly by the cubes, the smaller ones have gaps. Is my math wrong? Or did I hit some floating point weirdness?


You can use a math trick.
If you make the point count be twice the cube count + 1, you get the exact distribution of locations without any need to resize/cut the edges. All you need is to select the "odd" points and discard the even.
The only problem remaining is: you didn't define if you want constant cube sizes or stepped edge sizes. And I cannot do that for you, it's your decision. If the edges don't match the desired cube size, the cubes will have varying scales.

Some comments on the solution:

I converted to curve early so I can use "curve length" and stored only the essential attributes in the "spline" domain (this makes it simpler to deal with attributes)
I stored the "spline index" as an attribute because the "point indices" will alternate for each spline: spline 0, first point is "even", spline 1, first point is odd. I used the spline index to fix this alternation
The odd point selection is inside a frame for easy spotting
No need for extra calculations for cube scale. Cube scale = Cube length



